# Manipulate replace string in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
I have three variables in javascript like

var a = document.getElementById("txtOrderNumberRelease1").value;
var b  = document.getElementById("txtOrderNumberRelease2").value 
var c = document.getElementById("ddlOrderNumberRelease3");
```

and

```
var mainString ="ROAM-LCD-Synergy-789-456-LLX WARRANTY"
```

In mainString, the value "789" is coming from variable "a", 
value "456" is coming from variable b and value "LLX" is coming from variable "c".
Variables "a" and "b" will always be Integers, whereas variable "c" will always be one the three values ie. "LLI,LLA,LLX".

Before value "789", there can be any number of words splitted by hypen "-". like ROAM-LCD-Synergy-SSI etc...
But after the value of variable "c" i.e "LLX" in mainString, there can be only one word for eg. "WARRANTY".

Now my issue is, I have to replace these three values of "a","b" and "c"  ie. "789-456-LLX" with my newly entered values lets say  987-654-LLA, then my desired final string would be

old string:        mainString ="ROAM-LCD-Synergy-789-456-LLX WARRANTY"

desired string:    mainString ="ROAM-LCD-Synergy-987-654-LLA WARRANTY"

Please suggest some wayout.

Thanks

Comment: Don't attend computer science lectures when you're hungover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = 123; 
var b = 456; 
var c = "ABC";
var mainString ="ROAM-LCD-Synergy-789-456-LLX WARRANTY";

var updatedString = mainString .replace(/\d{3}-\d{3}-[A-Z]{3}\s([^\s]*)$/,a+"-"+b+"-"+c+" $1");
console.log(updatedString);
```

Comment: its working fine except in case of mystring"ROAM-123-456-LLX    No Cost" ie. when the last word in string has space i.e "NO COST".. but still trying it out..thanks..

Comment: I thought the last word was only on one word. You would just change [^\s] to [\s\w] so it would be `/\d{3}-\d{3}-[A-Z]{3}\s([\w\s]*)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
mainString.replace(/[\d]{3}\-[\d]{3}\-[\w]{3}\s([\w]+)$/, a + "-" + b + "-" + c + " $1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that uses string.split.

```
function replaceLastThreeDashedFields(original,a,b,c) {
    var spaceSplit = original.split(' ');
    var dashSplit = spaceSplit[0].split('-');
    dashSplit[dashSplit.length - 3] = a;
    dashSplit[dashSplit.length - 2] = b;
    dashSplit[dashSplit.length - 1] = c;
    var newDashed = dashSplit.join('-');
    spaceSplit[0] = newDashed;
    var newSpaced = spaceSplit.join(' ');
    return newSpaced;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, how about now? If this doesn't work, can you tell me what problem there is?

Answer (score -1):

The following code should update based on the values of a, b, and c...

```
var mainString ="ROAM-LCD-Synergy-789-456-LLX WARRANTY";

var a = document.getElementById("txtOrderNumberRelease1").value;
var b  = document.getElementById("txtOrderNumberRelease2").value;
var c = document.getElementById("ddlOrderNumberRelease3");

mainString = mainString.replace("789",a);
mainString = mainString.replace("456",b);
mainString = mainString.replace("LLX",c);
```

Comment: And when LLX is actually LLA? 789,456.LLX are dynamic, not known.

Comment: Umm.... Replace that with whatever you want then? It doesn't matter... Start with something that the regex can easily find, then replace it with the new... And if it's variable, then place the variable that held the previous value in the replace spot. Not sure why downvoted for correct answer?

Comment: If the original string is 'mainString', then you would replace 789 with a, 456 with b, and LLX with c

Comment: THE OP does not know what the values are up front, that is the issue.

Comment: Ok... Again, it does not matter. If , mainString starts as "ROAM-LCD-Synergy-789-456-LLX WARRANTY" - then the segments 789, 456, and LLX will be replaced with the correct parts - variables a, b, and c (how does no one get this?)

Comment: `replace("789"` <-- that "789" is UNKNOWN up front it can be any three numbers. That is what I was saying.

Comment: If this is the code being used to initialize mainString - var mainString ="ROAM-LCD-Synergy-789-456-LLX WARRANTY"; - then the "789" is known up front, based on the value of mainString. If this is not the code being used, then you are correct

Comment: I see what everyone is saying and what the correct answer is, but that is not what the question is asking...

Answer (score -1):

Just change the values before they are assigned? Place this before your variables are declared.

```
document.getElementById("txtOrderNumberRelease1").value = '987';
document.getElementById("txtOrderNumberRelease2").value = '654';
document.getElementById("txtOrderNumberRelease3").value = 'LLA';
```

Comment: How does this answer create the string `mainString ="ROAM-LCD-Synergy-987-654-LLA WARRANTY"`?